# separating one command from an array of commands with delimiter #

Tags: c

I am writing a TCP client application in c programming language, the project is a client server communication. I am  successfully communicating with the server, and the server is sending commands to me like a string, that I am saving that string in array of charts,and performing, but the problem is that sometimes the server is sending more then one command (max 3 commands) in this format
[100#100#100#] 100 is the command, and # is a sign so I know where the first command ends. 
So the problem is now how to divide all the commands in a separate char array? Any ides

P.S the problem why is this happening is because the client is written in c, and the server is written in java programming language, and the client should not be waiting for a ack from the server.

Comment: Use `strtok`. Search google for more on it. If you need reentrant version use `strtok_r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to divide the commands into separate `char` arrays - all you need is replacing `#`s with `\0`s within the array of characters that you received, and save the positions of the "breaks" in the string. Here is an illustration:

```
Index:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
       --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
Char:  '1' '0' '0' '#' '2' '0' '0' '#' '3' '0' '0' '#' \0
```

replace this with

```
Index:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
       --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
Char:  '1' '0' '0'  \0 '2' '0' '0' \0  '3' '0' '0' \0  \0
```

and store pointers to `&str[0]`, `&str[4]`, and `&str[8]` as pointers to your individual commands.

```
char[] str = "100#200#300#";
char *p1 = str;
char *p2 = strchr(p1, '#');
// Replace the first '#'
*p2++ = '\0';
// Replace the second '#'
char *p3 = strchr(p2, '#');
*p3++ = '\0';
// Replace the third '#'
*strchr(p3, '#') = '\0';
printf("One='%s' Two='%s' Three='%s'\n", p1, p2, p3);
```

This is only a demo: in production code you would need to check the return values of `strchr` before making assignments.

Comment: @SamFisher83 `strtok` not being thread safe is enough reason to rewrite this. Besides, using `strtok` for this is like swatting a fly with a hammer.

Comment: OK, thank you, this is working, but can you tell me how can I get p1, p2 and p3 like a variables, because I need to use them in some logic farther in my program?

Comment: @BiljanaTanceska What do you mean? `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are all local variables, you can pass them to other places in your program as you wish, as long as the `str` buffer has not been deallocated. You can make copies of them with `strdup` if you wish, or copy them to pre-allocated buffers with `memcpy` as well.

Comment: I understand now what are you trying to tell me, this is what I need it. Thnak you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char string[] ="100#100#100";
  char * commands;

  commands= strtok (str,"#");
  while (commands!= NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",commands);
    commands = strtok(NULL, "#");

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ManojAwasthi Please explain why you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: You should explain how your code works, not only for the OP, but also for future visitors who have a similar problem.

Comment: @MonadNewb Please check the answer submitted and read comments in there. You will understand.

Comment: This is wrong because it is missing a  `commands = strtok(NULL, "#");` in the control loop. As written, it will enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi I am not asking for my own understanding. I am asking that you back up your comment with the reasons in order to help future visitors weed out the wrong answers more easily. IMO, the information should be directly attached to this answer rather than directing people to look at the other answers which may be deleted or edited independently of this answer.

Comment: OK - @WhozCraig has already answered it - so resolved I think! :)

Comment: @MonadNewb I agree. Code-only answers are rarely helpful to anyone except the OP. Referencing other posts is valid only until they're pulled by their authors, then such references make no sense at all. A good answer stresses the *"why"*, not just the *"how"*.

Answer (score 0):

Use this implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char string[] ="100#100#100";
    char * commands;

    commands= strtok (string,"#");
    printf("%s\n", commands);   // <=== this is the first token 

    while (commands!= NULL) {
      commands= strtok (NULL,"#"); // <=== this will give further tokens 
                                   // Note - you need to call strtok again 
                                   // Note2 - you need to call with parameter NULL 
                                   //         for further tokens  
      printf ("%s\n",commands);
    }


   return 0;
}
```